# Checking if a column in a grouped set contain the same value, except the first row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am working on a rather large query, but am now stuck on the last bit. Given this example table:

```
  Key1  |  Key2  |  SomeCol  |
    0   |    0   |    ABC    |
    0   |    1   |    123    |
------------------------------
    1   |    5   |    ABC    |
    1   |    6   |    DEF    |
    1   |    7   |    ABC    |
------------------------------
    2   |    4   |    ABC    |
    2   |    5   |    456    |
    2   |    6   |    456    |
------------------------------
    3   |    4   |    ABC    |
    3   |    5   |    456    |
    3   |    6   |    ABC    |
------------------------------
    4   |    4   |    ABC    |
    4   |    5   |    ABC    |
    4   |    6   |    ABC    |
```

At this point in my query, I have extracted sequential(Key1, Key2) portions of a table and grouped by `Key1`. I wish to determine if all the values of `SomeCol` are identical, except for the first row.

```
Expected results:
  Key1  |  Key2  |  SomeCol  |
    0   |    0   |    ABC    |
    2   |    4   |    ABC    |
    4   |    4   |    ABC    |
```

I know I can use something like`.Any(g => g.SomeCol.Distinct().Count() == 1)` in a case where I need all entries to be the same, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the syntax right to `Skip(1)`. Also, I feel that my method of checking equality is sort of a hack. I know I can do this processing easily in C#, but I want to get as much of the processing to happen on the database side. Since my query is currently written in extension methods, I would appreciate in answer in the same syntax. Thanks!

What I have so far:

```
resultFromRestOfQuery
.GroupBy(g => g.Key1)
????
.SelectMany(g => g.Take(1).Select(h => h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Alright, tested this on your values and it works.

```
var result = collection
            .OrderBy(p => p.Key1)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Key2)
            .GroupBy(p => p.Key1)
            .Where(p => p.Skip(1)
                    .Select(j => j.SomeCol)
                    .Distinct().Count() == 1)
            .Select(p => p.First())
            .ToList();
```

**UPDATE #2**

Perhaps this will help you with performance. Here is another version of this query without using `Distinct()`. Note the `p.Count() > 1` - this is to avoid selecting the 1st row in a group when there's only 1 element in a group. If it's okay to select the first row when there's only one row, simply remove this part of the condition.

```
 var result = collection
            .OrderBy(p => p.Key1)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Key2)
            .GroupBy(p => p.Key1)
            .Where(p => p.Count() > 1 && p.Skip(1)
                    .Select(j => j.SomeCol)
                    .All(j => j == p.Last().SomeCol))
            .Select(p => p.First())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I had thought about skipping the first row prior to checking if all the `SomeCol` values were equal, but then I hit an issue where I am required to return that first row as the result.

Comment: Wait, do you mean the first row in the entire table, or the first row in each group of Key1?

Comment: The first row of each grouped collection. Take a look at the expected results I posted above. For each `Key1` I need to check if `SomeCol` is equivalent for `Min(Key2) + 1 to Max(Key2)`. If that condition is met, then return `(Key1, Min(Key2))`. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I managed to get your expected result from the data you provided. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is close, but your code does not work as intended in the case where the value of `SomeCol` is the same for a particular value of `Key1`. In the context of the problem, if the `SomeCol` value for key pairs (2,5) and (2,6) were changed to "ABC", the function will not return (2,4). I feel that this is really close though. I'll see if I can get this to work..

Comment: From what I understand, if `group[0].SomeCol` is **not** found in `group[1]` to `group[n]`, then return `group[0]`. Is that correct? That's what I see from the expected result you provided. So, if that is the case, if (2,5) and (2,6) had "ABC" for `SomeCol`, no value should be selected, like in your example with (1,6)(1,7). Where is my mistake?

Comment: From the question `I wish to determine if all the values of SomeCol are identical, except for the first row.` Using Key1 == 1 as an example, it does not return any values because (1,6).SomeCol != (1,7).SomeCol. The value of the first row, (1,5).SomeCol, should be ignored. I should have created better test cases. Will create more now

Comment: Ah, so if **ALL** the values of `SomeCol` in a group, except the first one, are the same, only then return `group[0]`? No problem. Updated my answer.

Comment: Your code now works. Initially, I was a little scared about using `.Distinct().Count()` to determine equality, but it doesn't seem to affect performance too much. The generated sql did multiply by about 4x though. Eeek! I would be interested in seeing other solutions before marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I posted another query that doesn't use distinct, perhaps it will run faster for you.